# Getting error 400 when calling an https request to apply a charge on Stripe API

Tags: node.js, https, stripe-payments, stringify, bad-request

I am using nodejs without any library/npm to make a charge on stripe using the test api key.

However I am always getting 400 status code response, and can't understand why, can someone give me an hint?

Here is my request details:

```
{ protocol: 'https:',
  hostname: 'api.stripe.com',
  method: 'POST',
  path: 'v1/charges',
  timeout: 5000,
  headers:
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Content-Length': 72 },
  auth: 'sk_test_JOXtNqPjvpFgLXMiwuWWKZxu:' }
```

And here is my payload (using querystring.stringify):

```
amount=5000&currency=usd&description=Tiago_1541865841578&source=tok_amex
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Here is the code, the method where I do the request it self:

```
helpers.sendRequest = function(protocol, port, hostname, method, path, timeoutSeconds, contentType, postData){

   // Stringify the payload
   var stringPayload = querystring.stringify(postData);

   // Construct the request
   var requestDetails = {
     'protocol' : protocol+':',
     'hostname' : hostname,
     'method' : method,
     'path' : path,
     'port' : port,
     'auth': ('Bearer ' + Buffer.from(config.stripe.secretApiKeyTest).toString('base64') + ":"),
     'timeout' : timeoutSeconds * 1000,
     'headers' :{
       'Authorization': ('Bearer ' + Buffer.from(config.stripe.secretApiKeyTest).toString('base64') + ":"),
       'teste':'ola',
       "teste2":"ola2",
       'Content-Type':contentType,
       'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload)
     }
   };

   console.log("Request Details:")
   console.log(requestDetails);
   console.log("Payload:")
   console.log(stringPayload);

   // Instantiate the request object (using either the http or https module)
   var _moduleToUse = protocol == 'http' ? http : https;
   var req = _moduleToUse.request(requestDetails, function(res){
       console.log(res.statusCode);

   });

   // Bind to the error event so it doesn't get thrown
   req.on('error',function(e){
     callback(err, e);
   });

   // Bind to the timeout event
   req.on('timeout',function(){
     callback(true, {'Error': 'The request took much time and got timeout.'})
   });

   // Add the payload
   req.write(stringPayload);

   // End the request
   req.end();
 };
```

And here is where I call the aux method to send the request:

```
var stripeRequestObject = {
                            amount: (totalPrice*100),
                            currency: 'usd',
                            description: userData.name+'_'+Date.now(),
                            source: stripeToken,
                        };

                        genericHelper.sendRequest('https',
                          443,
                          'api.stripe.com',
                          'POST',
                          'v1/charges',
                          5,
                          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                          stripeRequestObject);
```

Comment: I really do not understand why you wouldn't just use https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node for this. I know you said that you "need" to do this in plain Node, buy _why_? I'm curious.

Comment: Just a project and to learn :) no particular reason! I know there are bunches of libraries and modules that help a lot ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the auth you need to add *Bearer* before the token, that's how you send tokens to API. I tried to do the request on postman and it works, you can use axios or superagent to perform the request in you js file
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Pedro Silva thanks for your reply, I added the Bearer tag on the Authorization but still the request doesnt go though :(

Comment: Can you send me the full code you are using? In meantime, I will do a small script to try the request

Comment: Hey Pedro just updated the question with the code detailed, I hope it helps, I will keep searching and try to find out a solution... thanks

Comment: After analyzing your code, I realized it was too much complicated. So I created a simple script that you can adapt to your code that uses superagent to do the request pass all data you want as arguments and prints the results

https://pastebin.com/tJCJTx3r In this link, there is an example script with the code. 
Feel free to adapt it to your needs, if you need more help let me know. In case it solves you problems, mark the answer as correct pls :D

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort Pedro, the thing is that I need to do this in plain nodejs, without any kind of library or npm usage, That's why I am trying to use it using the https module of node itself, I will give it some more hours trial and error, in the meantime I will leave this question open if someone pops up with the solution using nodejs https module, thank you again!

Comment: I will try to use it them, if I can I will post it here

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yuEjtN2L Here you have it. You are putting to much things on the requestdetails may be unnecessary ones. Take a better look to my new example and see what's wrong. Now I think it has all you want

Comment: Thank you so much Pedro... it's too many hours in front of the monitor, now while comparing my code with yours I notice where was the problem! on path I am using 'v1/charges' while you use '/v1/charges' that was enough to cause the problem, after adding the slash '/' before 'v1' it started working properly, thank you so much for your time! all the best ;)

Comment: No problem, here to help :D

Answer (score 2):

That is how I did it.

```
const requestDetails = {
            protocol: 'https:',
            hostname: 'api.stripe.com',
            port: 443,
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/v1/charges',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload),
              Authorization: `Bearer ${config.stripe.testAPIkey.Secret}`
            }
          };
```

**There is a typo in your code**

```
'v1/charges'
```

**should be**

```
'/v1/charges'
```